# Unfold code on error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've found eclipse very annoing with error that occur in folded code, f.e.: imports.

Can this behavior be changed to unfold when error occurs?

I've checked conf, but nothing found.

Comment: just don't fold code

Comment: If you were really annoyed by this you could 1) download the source code for Eclipse, 2) implement this as a new feature, 3) submit a patch and see if they accept it.  But, I guess really annoyed is is relative :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the error in the 'Markers' tab (Window -> Show View -> Markers) the collapsed imports will be expanded.

Does this help a little bit?